# Handling Combinations of Props in Styled Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

I am trying to implement a material designed based button component using styled-components.  The component will have a number of props (such as size, icon, floating, etc).

It is getting rather overwhelming, though, to manage all the various combinations of props.

For instance, buttons come in three sizes:  default, small and large.

But the size of a small button changes based on whether or not it is a regular button or a floating button.  The same goes for a large button.

So I have the following sizes:

- Small
- Small Floating
- Default
- Floating
- Large
- Large Floating

And, of course, I have other combinations that I haven't listed.

As a result, my code is starting to get a bit convoluted as I have to not only check for the existence of a prop (`${props => { if (props.floating)...`), but also for whether or not that particular prop exists in combination with another prop (`${props => { if (props.floating && props.small)...`).

As such, I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to best organize and structure props when dealing with large numbers of combinations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind you can destructure within your instantiation. For example you might write like so:

```
${({ floating, small }) => {
    if (floating && small){
    ...
    }
}
```

It will cut down some of the bloat.

Comment: True (and it is better than what I am doing now).  But it's still a lot of if/else statements -- and I'm wondering if there is something more elegant that I am missing).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to keep my css separate, like in a `styles.js` file. Take the following code for example. It keeps the css organized, and makes implementing the different options pretty clean. Of course, add your css into the appropriate definitions

```
//styles.js
import { css } from 'styled-components';

export const buttonbase = css`/*base styles for all buttons*/`;
export const small = css`/*small size styles*/`;
export const medium = css`/*default size styles*/`;
export const large = css`/*large size styles*/`;
export const floating = css`/*float styles*/`;
```

And in your component file:

```
//Button.js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import * as Styles from './styles';

const propTypes = {
  floating: PropTypes.bool,
  size: PropTypes.oneOf(['small', 'medium', 'large']),
  children: PropTypes.node,
};

const defaultProps = {
  floating: false,
  size: 'medium',
};

const ButtonBase = styled.button`
  ${Styles.buttonbase};
  ${props => (props.floating ? Styles.floating : '')};
  ${props => Styles[props.size]};
`;

const Button = ({ floating, size, children, ...rest }) => (
  <ButtonBase
    size={size}
    floating={floating}
    {...rest}
  >
    {children}
  </ButtonBase>
);

Button.propTypes = propTypes;
Button.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Button;
```

The result would be, say given these values:

```
export const buttonbase = css`
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
`;
export const medium = css`
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 30px;
`;
export const floating = css`
  float: left;
`;
```

And this component:

```
<Button size="medium" floating />
```

The `<ButtonBase/>` component puts together `buttonbase`, `medium`, and `floating` from the imported styles, generating the complete style:

```
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
```

Comment: I like the organization of this system, but I am wondering how it works with the various combinations.  I can see how I can easily set a size or determine whether or not the button is a floating button, but how do I combine the size with a floating button?

Comment: @Moshe Assuming the size only sets size, and floating does not change the size, the `<ButtonBase/>` component is combining the imported styles. I'll add a brief explanation to the answer...

Comment: In my case there is one size for a regular button and different one for a floating button.  So, for instance, in your example above:  regular medium would be `font-size: 16px; height: 30px;` whereas floating medium could be `font-size: 18px; height: 36px;`

I am wondering how your system would handle that?

Comment: @Moshe It's hard for me to say without seeing complete definitions for these variables. I try to keep responsibilities separated, so only a `size` prop would change the size. My implementation of this component also includes a number of other props, but each is semantically related to it's function.

Comment: okay - makes sense.  One possible solution for me may be to make a separate FloatingButton -- with it's own size prop.  I'll experiment with it tomorrow and see what works best.  Either way, thanks for the help -- I like the idea of separating responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I use a package called [styled-is](https://github.com/yldio/styled-is) to help style my styled-components, it comes with helper functions you just use directly with styled-components.

Comment: This is neat. Thanks for sharing.